# Install Vulkan in Debian

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, vulkan

I have a Nvidia GeForce 845M card. I wish to install the driver for NVIDIA Vulkan in my Debian 8.

I followed these steps without luck.

1. I go to [web](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver). I selected Download for Linux 64-bit:
   [image]

Below you can see a list of supported cards:
[image]

I can't see my card.

But in the [download page](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/104284) I can see my card:
[image]

2. When I downloaded the driver i do:

   ```
   $ chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run

   $ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run
   ```

But this errors show up:

[image]

[image]

Here's the log:
[/var/log/nvidia-installer.log](https://gist.github.com/rpayanm/1122e9b9d36f604797e7f081adb0a555)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your installer log says that an X server is running.  You might try doing whatever it takes to get to a text shell prompt with no X server running.

Whenever I install these drivers on an Ubuntu system, I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a text shell and kill the X server with `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`.

Then I run the `.run` file.